# Logback DB appender not working with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, slf4j, logback

I am using logback with spring boot.
I configured logback.xml but log data is not inserting into db.
It's reading the DB appender properties as per console.
Please help me.

```html
 

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/basic.xml"/>
 <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
   <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
   </Pattern>
  </layout>
 </appender>

 
 <appender name="DB" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
  <connectionSource
   class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
   <driverClass>org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
   <url>jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/twitter</url>
   <user>root</user>
   <password>*****</password>
  </connectionSource>
 </appender>
 <root level="INFO">
  <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  <appender-ref ref="DB" />
 </root>

</configuration>
```

Console Log is provided below:

```
18:50:01,920 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/D:/git/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml]
18:50:01,955 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
18:50:01,965 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.IncludeAction - Could not find resource corresponding to [org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/basic.xml]
18:50:01,965 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
18:50:01,967 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
18:50:02,011 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - This appender no longer admits a layout as a sub-component, set an encoder instead.
18:50:02,011 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - To ensure compatibility, wrapping your layout in LayoutWrappingEncoder.
18:50:02,011 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - See also http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#layoutInsteadOfEncoder for details
18:50:02,011 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender]
18:50:02,015 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [DB]
18:50:02,057 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource@e8757ef - Driver name=MariaDB connector/J
18:50:02,057 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource@e8757ef - Driver version=1.2.3
18:50:02,057 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource@e8757ef - supportsGetGeneratedKeys=true
18:50:02,060 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to ERROR
18:50:02,060 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
18:50:02,061 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [DB] to Logger[ROOT]
18:50:02,061 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
18:50:02,062 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@20e21368 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
```

Comment: How are you configuring logback? Are you aware that Spring Boot ignores -Dlogback.configurationFile?

Comment: Included logback.xml in the class path(inside resources). I can see that configuration is loading.

Comment: What do you mean by "It's reading the DB appender properties as per console." ? Because there is also a ConsoleAppender in your file.

Comment: I configured both console, db appenders. I am facing problem with DB appender only. In the console it's clearly showing that it's reading database connection details

Comment: I got the problem. I didn't use the updated logback sql schema. Can you guys close the issue.

Comment: Answer your own question and accept it, i'd like to see what you've done to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the logback database tables updated or night.
MySql schema location:logback-classic-X.X.X.jar\ch\qos\logback\classic\db\script*.sql